# Using DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, user-interface, ado.net

In my application i have datagrid with simple type of cells - string, integer.

I want to change one of the cell from string to be combobox.

i try to populate the in each line different inomration, but did not see anything.
It means that i see comboBox in each cell of the column but the comboBox is empty.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmdParam1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmdParam1.Name = "cmdParam1";
cmdParam1.HeaderText = "cmdParam1";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmdParam1);

DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)    (dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells["cmdParam1"]);
cell.DataSource = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" }; 

cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells["cmdParam1"]);
cell.DataSource = new string[] { "4", "5", "6" };
```

Thanks

Nir

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assiging string array to datasource try below code:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) (dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells["cmdParam1"]);
            cell.Items.Add("1");
            cell.Items.Add("2");
            cell.Items.Add("3");


DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell) (dataGridView1.Rows[4].Cells["cmdParam1"]);
            cell.Items.Add("4");
            cell.Items.Add("5");
            cell.Items.Add("6");
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to track down something similar. Turns out you can't edit cells (ie. select items from a `ComboBox`) if you've got `FullRowSelect` turned on.